# WooCommerce Points and Rewards and discount rounds up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, points, discount

I am using WooCommerce Points and Rewards plugin. The issue I have is when applying points to cart, it is rounding up to the nearest integer. I would like for it to apply in cents.

For example: `10 points = 1 dollar`. If customer has **`11`** points so the discount should be **`$1.10`, but not `$2.00`**. I've looked through the plugin code but do not see where this is being force to round up.

Any advise or thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin round the points on the displayed cart notice… **You can't apply in cents**… You can only tune in the plugin settings the **"Earn Points Rounding Mode"** and the best round mode is: **"Round to nearest integer"**…

What you can do is to fix **a minimal number of points** to get the discount and display the related notice with the folowing code *(Fixed to 100 points below)*:

```
// Points and rewards conditional redeem points message display up to 100 points
add_filter( 'wc_points_rewards_redeem_points_message', 'conditional_redeem_points_message', 10, 2 );
function conditional_redeem_points_message( $message, $discount_available ){
    $points  = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::calculate_points_for_discount( $discount_available );
    if( $points >= 100 ) 
        return $message;
    else
        return '';
}
```

And in the plugin settings you will Fix the same number for **"Maximum Points Discount"**.

> So the notice will be displayed **only for this minimal number of points** and the available cart discount **will be a real corresponding integer amount**…

I haven't find already another way.